# What is best practice in Blazor: Put much business logic to *.razor file or in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

[I've read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#request-a-service-in-a-component).

We have 2 directions:

- Put much business logic code at *.razor* file inside `@code{ ... }`. Therefore, We inject **databaseContext** to inside `*.razor`. Then check validation, mapping object, query database in `@code{...}`

For example

```
@page "/foos"
@using BlalaProject.Models
@inject BlalaProject.Data ApplicationDbContext

<h1>List of Foos</h1>

@if (FooList == null)
{
    <p>
        <em>Loaidng...</em>
    </p>
}
else
{
    <DxDataGrid Data="@FooList" PageSize="20" ShowFilterRow="true">
        <DxDataGridCommandColumn Width="150px"></DxDataGridCommandColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Foo.FooName)" Caption="@("Foo name")" TextAlignment="@DataGridTextAlign.Left"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridSpinEditColumn Field="@nameof(Foo.ParentId)" Caption="@("Parent of Foo")"></DxDataGridSpinEditColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Foo.FooNameEnglish)" Caption="@("Foo name in English")" TextAlignment="@DataGridTextAlign.Left"></DxDataGridColumn>
    </DxDataGrid>
}

@code {

    IEnumerable<Foo> FooList

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        IEnumerable<Foo> FooList = await Data ApplicationDbContext.Foo.List();
       // so much business logic at here, because this page has not controller
       .... 
    }
}
```

- Put much business logic code at Controller. Therefore, We inject **databaseContext** to Controller, then inject **controller** into **.razor*

For example, File `Foos.razor`

```
@page "/foos"
@using BlalaProject.Models
@inject BlalaProject.Controllers.FooController Controller

<h1>List of Foos</h1>

@if (FooList == null)
{
    <p>
        <em>Loaidng...</em>
    </p>
}
else
{
    <DxDataGrid Data="@FooList" PageSize="20" ShowFilterRow="true">
        <DxDataGridCommandColumn Width="150px"></DxDataGridCommandColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Foo.FooName)" Caption="@("Foo name")" TextAlignment="@DataGridTextAlign.Left"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridSpinEditColumn Field="@nameof(Foo.ParentId)" Caption="@("Parent of Foo")"></DxDataGridSpinEditColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(Foo.FooNameEnglish)" Caption="@("Foo name in English")" TextAlignment="@DataGridTextAlign.Left"></DxDataGridColumn>
    </DxDataGrid>
}

@code {
    IEnumerable<Foo> FooList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        FooList = await Controller.GetFooAsync();    
    }
}
```

and in `Startup.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using BlalaProject.Areas.Identity;
using BlalaProject.Data;
using BlalaProject.Controllers;

namespace BlalaProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            services.AddSingleton<FooController>();
            services.AddSingleton<BarController>();
            services.AddSingleton<BaaController>();
            services.AddSingleton<FuuController>();
            services.AddSingleton<FuzController>();
            services.AddSingleton<FzuController>();
            services.AddSingleton<BaaaController>();
            services.AddSingleton<FoobarController>();
            services.AddSingleton<BarFooController>();
            services.AddSingleton<BaaFuuuController>();
            services.AddSingleton<BaFooBaController>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }

}
```

What is the best practices or other solution? What should inject to *.razor* is best practices in application has many business logic?

Answer (score 1):

A view should only care about displaying/formatting the data, maybe to do minor calculations with the "ViewModel". Putting business logic, let alone database calls there is an anti pattern. View would your "view" care about how the data is retrieved? You should just pass it's model to it. Here is a great little [article](https://itnext.io/a-simple-mvvm-implementation-in-client-side-blazor-8c875c365435?gi=b5e888ce3aba) with a similar approach (repository logic is part of model here), and here is [another one](https://diatomenterprises.com/asp-net-mvc-business-logic-as-a-separate-layer/) for ASP.NET where you can get the gist of why it is important to separate the layers to promote extensibility/maintainability.

Repository calls/logic should go either into the controller if its "thin" or have a separate service layer depending on the thickness of you domain. For example if you implemented as above, whenever you would have to change the logic to retrieve data from some source database/service call/whatnot you would always have to change your view, but it should have no business with that.

I would advise the following:

1. View should only fomat/display the data
2. The ViewModel can contain business logic to map the data model/calculate whats necessary
3. You can either inject your repository into the controller or devise a middle layer for services
4. Try to follow the [SOLID](https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles) principles

Comment: Why put `@code{.. }` inside `*.razor`? Is it for business logic? :)

Comment: It is for linking to your business logic.

Comment: Though I agree that immediate data access through the context in the component is not expedient, squeezing additional layers of abstraction between UI and Model that go beyond a controller or service smells like just another anti-pattern. Blazor's component-based approach achieves SOC (which really is the only aspect of SOLID to which OP's question boils down here) mainly on a logical layer rather than multiple vertical abstractions (like React does for instance). Also, if you consider the code-behind approach, top-level Blazor components can be seen as a View+ViewModel themselves.